# Inserting a variable in a script

Tags: php

I'm learning a little bit of PHP and JSON to make a simple CRUD. I have different categories divided into nodes, I don't want to have to create an individual add page for each node and I'm trying to fetch the categories(node) from URL. I'm fetching the category from the URL with a get, the variable it's fine but I think I'm not using the correct syntax to insert that variable on the rest of the code.

```
<?php $type = $_GET["type"]; ?>

<h1>You are adding a new type of: <?php echo $type ?></h1>
<form action="add.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Code"/>
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price"/>
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description"/>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="photo">
    <input type="submit" name="add"/>

</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    $file = file_get_contents('menu.json');
    $data = json_decode($file, true);
    unset($_POST["add"]);
    $data[" '.$type.' "] = array_values($data[" '.$type.' "]);
    array_push($data[" '.$type.' "], $_POST);
    file_put_contents("menu.json", json_encode($data));
    header("Location: backend.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Not your current issue... but... you are open to XSS injections with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to lose your $_GET value as soon as you submit your form since your action is just 'add.php'.

Either use `action="add.php?type=<?php echo $type ?>"` or just exclude the action which by default will submit to the current url.

---

Like pointed out, you're subject to XSS injections with this code.  Encode html entities on type to prevent this.  (Always encode user input before outputting to the browser):

```
<?php $type = htmlentities($_GET["type"]); ?>
```